# Is 微妙で繊細な a redundant phrase?

Tags: meaning

Consider the following sentence.

> 日本の料理{りょうり}ほど微妙{びみょう}で、繊細{せんさい}なものはない。

Is 微妙で繊細な a redundant phrase?

Comment: I can't say for sure, but I feel like 微妙 would usually not be used that way. Might be interpreted as a bad thing. Also I sort of feel like は should be が, but I could be wrong.

Comment: @stackreader 日本料理ほど繊細なもの は ない means nothing is more delicate than Japanese cuisine while 日本料理ほど繊細なもの が ない means they don't have something so delicate as Japanese cuisine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although 微妙 and 繊細 refer to similar things ("delicate"), this sentence looks just fine to me. IMHO Calling this a redundant sentence is bit too nitpicky.

Actually, you should not use 微妙 alone in this case. 微妙 is a nuanced word these days and it may mean negative things depending on the context. (See: [Why does 微妙 become "sucky" in slang usage?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/3346/5010)) If you said 日本の料理ほど微妙なものはない, it might mean something negative. If you combine 微妙 with 繊細, there is no room for misunderstanding because 繊細 has a positive connotation.