# のですませてる人 meaning

Tags: translation

I'm trying to translate the following sentence:

> なんでも｢微妙｣｢｣のですませてる人がいますが、その意味がわかりません

My attempt is:

There are people who get by with the word 'bimyou' in any kind of situation, but I don't understand the meaning of this word.

My problem is specifically with のですませてる人. It seems like, 'people who get by with...' Is this correct? To make matters worse it is preceded by two sets of quotation marks, which makes it all the more confusing.

Also, a clarification of なんでも would be appreciated. I read it as 'in any situation' but am not confident with this rendering.

Thanks.

Edit: I have realised, on further reflection, the sentence might be a mistranscription due to an ICR error, as suggested by naruto in the comments below. I copy-pasted the sentence in question from a Word file. Accordingly, the sentence should be:

> なんでも｢微妙｣ですませてる人がいますが、その意味がわかりません

With the errors omitted.

Comment: Where is the sentence from? I'm curious about the two sets of quotation marks too.

Comment: It's from a reading I'm doing. It is taken from a book that discusses problematic expressions that have been adopted in Japanese. I think the title is Mondai na Nihongo.

Comment: Is there really の before で? And is there really empty brackets?

Comment: Yes, I copy-pasted. The sentence might be a mistranscription; I found it confusing, too.

Comment: What is the larger context?  That might help make sense of the grammar here, and, if there is a typo, make sense of what the correction should be.

Comment: Then can it be an OCR-error? Anyway, the correct sentence must be `なんでも「微妙」ですませている人がいます` without の or empty brackets.

Comment: Possibly. I had to look up OCR. I'll update my question accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> なんでも｢微妙｣ですませてる人がいますが、その意味がわかりません。
>
> There are people who get by with the word 'bimyou' in any kind of situation, but I don't understand the meaning of this word.

I think your attempt for the first half of the sentence is okay. See other examples of ～で済ませる [here](http://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=%E3%81%A7%E6%B8%88%E3%81%BE%E3%81%9B%E3%82%8B&ref=sa) and [here](http://ejje.weblio.jp/sentence/content/%22%E3%81%A7%E6%B8%88%E3%81%BE%E3%81%9B%E3%82%8B%22).

For the last half, this その意味が分かりません is probably more like "Such a way of using 微妙 makes no sense to me" or "I don't agree with that." 意味がわからない or 意味わかんない often just means "That's absurd!"

(For those interested in why 微妙 is a disputed word, see [Why does 微妙 become "sucky" in slang usage?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/3346/5010) I personally know some people who say 微妙 habitually.)

Answer (score 1):

**なんでも｢微妙｣ですませてる人がいますが、その意味がわかりません。**

***There are people who always answer "it is bimyo (I/we can't decide yes or no, or I/we can't give a clear answer to it because the matter is very delicate/controversial)" to every question, but I cannot agree with their attitude.***

***There are extraordinary indecisive people in Japan, always answering "it's bimyo", but I don't know/understand their attitude.***

I think this is an interpretation of what the original Japanese meant.

Comment: I think to marry the original feel with what is being said, "There are people who use "bimyo" for anything, but I don't understand exactly why"