# 微妙に大きく problem translating/understanding

Tags: translation, meaning

I'm reading the university journal article [『カタカナ英語{えいご}と和製英語{わせいえいご}：最近{さいきん}の傾向{けいこう}を中心{ちゅうしん}として』](https://ci.nii.ac.jp/naid/110009935033), and the following sentence came up.

> 以下{いか}は日本語{にほんご}と英語{えいご}では意味{いみ}が**微妙{びみょう}に大{おお}きく**異{こと}なる和製英語{わせいえいご}である

My reading of this would be:

Below is waseigo where the English and Japanese meaning is very different (in a complicated/doubtful/tricky way?) The juxtaposition of 微妙 and 大きく is confusing since they seem to carry opposite meanings (big and small/subtle). Can someone give me a better explanation/translation so that I can understand this sentence.

Comment: I do have something of an answer, but if you list the words they use as example, we may be able to better answer the question.

Comment: 「微妙に大きく異なる」って‥？ちょっと意味わかんないんですけど（私だけ？）、「微妙に大きく」をググると「微妙に大きくて」「微妙に大きくなって」とかいう感じで、「少しサイズが大きい」「少し大きくなった」（a little too big / grew a little bigger）みたいな意味 (微妙に adverbially modifies the adjective 大きい) のしか見当たらないですね・・。「微妙に大きく異なる」では、「微妙に」も「大きく」も両方、「異なる」を修飾してる感じがしますけど、それって変ですよね・・

Comment: 「微妙に」が「異なる」の質、「大きく」が度合い、ってことなのかな？

Comment: That loan words have the same meaning in some situations but has a big difference in some situation. You need to be careful about how to use it in some situation of both languages. I assume there are those words in the paper. I personally don't suppose that "微妙に大きく異なる” is so jargon or something, but it's paradoxical and may be used in a small group in academia.

Comment: まあこういう用法も[まれによくある](http://www.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%BE%E3%82%8C%E3%81%AB%E3%82%88%E3%81%8F%E3%81%82%E3%82%8B)と思います（笑）

Comment: It's worth noting the article is from essentially a 紀要 which means it's quite possibly not been subject to peer review or much editing, *lector emptor*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

微妙 is an overused word recently, and it may mean something as simple as "**kinda**". To me, 微妙に大きく異なる sounds like "there are kinda large differences". So it basically expresses the uncertainty; he may have felt 大きく was an overstatement.

This usage of 微妙に is slangy, and should definitely be avoided in serious articles like this. Therefore I would say his wording here is a "非常に[微妙な](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/3346/5010)表現"! (非常に微妙, meaning something like "highly questionable", is another slangy and disputed expression that seems contradictory :D)

Answer (score -1):

> 以下は日本語と英語では意味が**微妙に大きく**異なる和製英語である｡

「マイブーム」の質問があったのと同じ論文で、しかも同じ副題「３）日英で異なる意味の和製英語
」の中の文章ですね。

「微妙に大きく異なる」は、
意味は「大きく異なる」が、各々の意味が属している分野は「似ている」という程度の意味です。
例えば「ブックカバー」は、英語と日本語とでは違うものを指していますが、所属する分野は本、書籍なので同じです。
*The meaning of "微妙に異なる" is "very different" but what are meant have the same point such as belonging to the same field. For example, "book cover" and "ブックカバー" refer to something different between English and Japanese, but each one belongs to the same field of books*.

「微妙に大きく異なる」を別の言葉で言うと「全｛まった｝く違｛ちが｝うとは言｛い｝い難｛がた｝い」でしょうか。

> 参考掲載：
>
> ３) 日英で異なる意味の和製英語 **以下は日本語と英語では意味が微妙に大きく異なる和製英語である｡** 例えば､｢デッドヒート｣は英語では日本語のように｢激しい競り合い｣を意味するものではなく、｢同直で勝ち負けが成立しない試合またはレース｣の意味である｡また｢ベビーカー｣は日本語のような｢赤ん坊を寝かせて運ぶもの｣の意味は英語にはなく｢小型自動車｣の意味である｡以下その他の実例である｡
>
> - ブックカバー(book wrapper, (dust)jacket) (英語で言えば｢表紙｣の意味)
> - マイブーム((temporary) personal obsession) (英語で言えば｢私のにわか景気｣
>   の意｡
> - デノミネーション[100円を１円にするような通貨の呼称単位の切り下げ] ((currency)
>   redenomination [revaluation]; dropping [trimming, lopping] 《two》zeroes 《from the yen》; [通貨の呼称単位の変更] renaming a monetary unit; (a) redesignation [change] of the name of a monetary unit (英語で言えば単に｢貨幣の単位｣の意味で､日英で別のものを指す)
> - ベビーカー(baby carriage; pram) (英語で言えば｢小型の車｣
> - ミキサー(blender) (英語で言えば｢大型工業用ミキサー｣
> - フェミニスト[女性崇拝者] (admirer [adorer] of women; ladies' [lady's] man; [女に甘い男] man who is unusually kind [obliging] to women; chivalrous [gallant] man (英語で言えば｢女権拡張論者｣)
> - バイキングsmorgasbord; all-you-caneat buffet (英語では８～11世紀に活躍した北欧人)
> - クレームcomplaint; objection (英語では｢請求・要求・主張｣)
> - カンニングcheating (in an examination) ; cribbing (英語で言えば｢狡猾な｣)

---

## EDIT

@ǝʇɐןoɔoɥƆさんのコメントを見て、日本人にも「微妙に大きく異なる」の意味は、それを理解するのが難しいのだろうと判断しました。まして、ＯＰが理解するのはかなり難しいのでしょう。

どうしたら、少しでも理解いただけるか似た表現である「微妙に異なる」も登場させて説明してみます。少しでもニュアンスをつかんでいただけたらありがたいと思います。

「微妙に異なる」：似ているが何となく違う（＝異なる）。
「微妙に大きく異なる」：大変違う（＝大きく異なる）が何となく似ている。

なぜこのような意味になるのでしょうか。

「微妙に」によって、「異なる」あるいは「大きく異なる」と言い切るのを少しためらっていると考えるとどうでしょう。

「微妙に異なる」：→「異なる」と言い切るには「微妙」である→「異なる」と言い切るのを「ためらう」→では同じかと言うと、同じだというには少し違う。→何故なら、似ているが何となく違う（＝異なる）。

「微妙に大きく異なる」：「大きく異なる」と言い切るには「微妙」である→「大きく異なる」と言い切るのを「ためらう」→何故なら、大変違う（＝大きく異なる）が何となく似ている。

「微妙に大きく異なる」に関しては別の解釈の仕方がある。「微妙に」+「大きく」+「異なる」なので、「微妙に大きく」だけを考える。
「微妙に大きく」は、「大きく」と言い切るには「微妙」であると言う意味になり、結局、「異なることは異なる」が「大きくとまでは言い切れない」となる。言い換えると、「大きく異なる」と言い切るには「少しは似ているところがある」のでちょっと言い切るのはやめてというような感じである。

結果として、
「微妙に大きく異なる」は、大変違う（＝大きく異なる）が何となく似ている。
私の答えでは、「ブックカバー」と「book cover」を例に出して、基本的に違うものだが、分野が同じということで「完全に違うと言い切れない」ような説明をしたつもりです。

Comment: I know this is a quote, but ミクサー is neither wasei-eigo, nor there is a difference https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixer_(cooking)

Comment: @macraf: 確かに、この論文は、ミクサー（typo of ミキサー?）を含めて裏付け調査が不十分な気がします。Certainly, this paper seems to be inadequately supported, including ミクサー (typo of ミキサー?).

Comment: There is a difference, though – in Japanese it means 'blender', and that's why they call it 和製英語.

Comment: So: have a big difference but somewhat resemble each other (have a big difference in a subtlely different category which has a resemblance). E.g. Babycar: Japanese: pram English: small car.

Comment: @Robert: kimiさんの回答に対してkimiさん自身がmackygoo宛てにコメントしていますがすばらしい理解だと思います。「微妙に大きく異なる」ことを「階層 layer」で説明しています。例えばbook coverとブックカバーとでは「ある階層」で見ると共通だが、その下位階層では全く違うと論理的に説明しています。